# GLM errror quasi family R

Tags: r, glm, variance

I am trying to fit a GLM specifying the relation between mean and variance with the help of the `quasi` family.
The issue is that I cannot fit the model for some particular variance assumptions.
More specifically if I set it to `mu^2` everything is fine, but I set it to `mu^3` it breaks with a weird error.
Here the code

```
data <- structure(list(origin = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                            3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                            5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"
), class = "factor"), dev = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
                                        8L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 
                                        4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
                                        5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
                                        3L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "10", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
                                                            "8", "9"), class = "factor"), amount = c(5012, 3257, 2638, 898, 
                                                                                                     1734, 2642, 1828, 599, 54, 172, 106, 4179, 1111, 5270, 3116, 
                                                                                                     1817, 100, 673, 535, 3410, 5582, 4881, 2268, 2594, 3479, 649, 
                                                                                                     603, 5655, 5900, 4211, 5500, 2159, 2658, 984, 1092, 8473, 6271, 
                                                                                                     6333, 3786, 225, 1513, 4932, 5257, 1233, 2917, 557, 3463, 6926, 
                                                                                                     1368, 1351, 5596, 6165, 3133, 2262, 2063)), class = c("data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -55L))

glm(amount~., data = data, family=quasi(link = "log", variance = "mu^2"))
glm(amount~., data = data, family=quasi(link = "log", variance = "mu^3"))
```

As you can see, the first glm is perfectly working but the second fails.
What am I missing here?
Thank you very much

Comment: It would be better if you actually displayed the output/errors you're getting in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is helpful if you give us the error message. Using your code:

```
glm(amount~., data = data, family=quasi(link = "log", variance = "mu^3"))
```

The error message is:

```
Error: inner loop 1; cannot correct step size
In addition: Warning message:
step size truncated due to divergence
```

By searching for this error message, you can often find answers to what it means. According to this post (https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/glm-error-cannot-correct-step-size-td990913.html), it is a model convergence issue. Which might suggest that the variance structure "mu^3" is not appropriate for your data. When models don't converge sometimes using `scale()` on continuous predictors helps (not appropriate here since you have specified both `origin` and `dev` as factors). But, you can also drop terms to help.

```
glm(amount~origin+dev, data = data, family=quasi(link = "log", variance = "mu^3"))
```

This is the same as your initial model that didn't work (just replaced `.` with your only predictors `origin` and `dev`) - meaning this model doesn't work. But if we drop `origin` or `dev` they converge fine:

```
glm(amount~origin, data = data, family=quasi(link = "log", variance = "mu^3"))
glm(amount~dev, data = data, family=quasi(link = "log", variance = "mu^3"))
```

If you are simply looking for the best fit both of the following work fine as well. However, you would want to understand the differences here before choosing these other options:

```
glm(amount~., data = data, family=quasi(link = "log", variance = "mu"))
glm(amount~., data = data, family=quasi(link = "log", variance = "constant"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that I am trying different relations between the mean and the variance in my data to understand which one is the most appropriate. This is why I have `mu^2` and `mu^3`. Moreover I can't drop the predictors because I need the outcome to be different based on both `origin` and `dev`.

Comment: "... to understand which one is the most appropriate." - yes, and I believe the fact that the model didn't converge (error message) is indicative of `mu^3` not being appropriate.